# Get datetime value from registry

Tags: c#, casting, datetime-format

hi i save datetime value to registry by this code

```
string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ITC";
string keyValue = "test";
string valueT1 = "T1";
string valueT2 = "T2";

 DateTime dateT1 = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime dateT2 = dateT1.AddDays(180);
 Registry.SetValue(keyName, valueT1, dateT1);
 Registry.SetValue(keyName, valueT2, dateT2);
```

but when i try to get that value again by this code

```
DateTime regTime1;
DateTime regTime2;
regTime1 = (DateTime) Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueT1, null);
regTime2 = (DateTime)Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueT2, null);
```

it's give error  "**Spesified cast is not valid**"
any idea how to do it rightly?

Comment: It's probably saved as a string in the registry. Save it to the registry in a specific format, and read it out using datetime.parse using the same format

Comment: Did you look at the values in RegEdit to see what type they ended up being? As you didn't specify a type when you wrote them, they probably ended up being strings (`REG_SZ`).

Comment: @DavidLibido can you give me example how to save it to spesific format because as i see in detail .setValue it's not give information how to do it

Comment: @KenWhite the value saved in registry is "12/23/2014 4:54:42 PM" yeah it's REG_SZ...do you have idea how to spesifict type to save in datetime format?

Comment: Note that you'd be better off converting date to string (with `"O"` format specifier) and storing resulting string... Parse after reading as string. Less interesting, but way more readable code and guaranteed to do what you want.

Comment: The registry doesn't have a datetime format. The easiest way to deal with it is probably to write it as a string *and* specify the format you want (eg., 'CCYYMMDDHHMMSS`), and then read it back and parse it accordingly into a `DateTime`. Or write it as binary data (`REG_BINARY`) and read it back into a double and then convert that to a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably write/read DateTime to the registry with the following methods

These methods are storing the DateTime in the `QWORD` registry format (A 64-bit binary number)

```
public static void SetDate(string keyName, string valueName, DateTime dateTime) 
{
   Registry.SetValue(keyName,valueName, dateTime.ToBinary(), RegistryValueKind.QWord);
}

public static DateTime GetDate(string keyName, string valueName)
{
   var result = (long)Registry.GetValue(keyName,valueName);
   return DateTime.FromBinary(result);
}
```

**Note : there is no error checking here, and please do due-diligence before using them**

the registry is not the place to be playing if you are unsure

Comment: ...the registry is like every other place in windows. I on the contrary encourage to play with it ;-) you can hurt your system every where and the registry is in no way special. just another playground.

Comment: @t3chb0t, Fair comment, and i like your youthful exuberance, you can vote up my answer now :)

Comment: Here you are... I have another 39 to spend today so be the first ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed, however under .NET 4.5, `Registry.GetValue()` shows params of `string keyName`, `string valueName`, and `object defaultValue`.  There's no mention of an overload that takes a `RegistryValueKind`.  Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Memetican yes you are correct and it was seemingly a mistake, you can pass in a default value or just omit the parameter

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
DateTime dateTime1;
if (DateTime.TryParse((string)Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueT1, DateTime.MinValue),
    out dateTime1))
{
     ........      
}
```